# How to make cover photo from image?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

My app has a cover photo feature and I have no idea on how to do it after taking a picture/upload from photo library.

How do I allow user to pick a portion of their photo to be their cover photo(example from the screenshot below)?

[[image: Example from the Twitter app[1]]

Comment: have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011671/crop-image-to-a-square-according-to-the-size-of-a-uiview-cgrect?

Comment: Yes but I'm still unsure how to have a box to drag and crop that portion out only

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can take a photo then present it in a VC like this   and then use gestures to drag the box around while performing the action on choose to crop the image within those bounds. I am sure there must be some thirdparty resource for this. Like this https://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor . You can translate it to swift I assume